# Extract two columns sorted from CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a large csv file, containing multiple values, in the form

```
Date,Dslam_Name,Card,Port,Ani,DownStream,UpStream,Status
2020-01-03 07:10:01,aart-m1-m1,204,57,302xxxxxxxxx,0,0,down
```

I want to extract the `Dslam_Name` and `Ani` values, sort them by `Dslam_name` and write them to a new csv in two different columns.

So far my code is as follows:

```py
import csv
import operator

with open('bad_voice_ports.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    sortedlist = sorted(readCSV, key=operator.itemgetter(1)) 
    for row in sortedlist:
        bad_port = row[1][:4],row[4][2::]
        print(bad_port)
        f = open("bad_voice_portsnew20200103SORTED.csv","a+")
        f.write(row[1][:4] + " " + row[4][2::] + '\n')
        f.close()
```

But my `Dslam_Name` and `Ani` values are kept in the same column.

As a next step I would like to count how many times the same value appears in the 1st column.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to learn how to use `pandas`. It is a library that is perfect for manipulating files such as CSVs. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) is a good place to start!

Comment: This is a good start https://realpython.com/python-csv/  How to read and write csv with python.

Comment: I've read that pandas is the best solution but I'm having trouble installing them so I'm trying to find another solution until I'll sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forcing them to be a single column.  Joining the two into a single string means Python no longer regards them as separate.

But try this instead:

```py
import csv
import operator

with open('bad_voice_ports.csv') as readfile, open('bad_voice_portsnew20200103SORTED.csv', 'w') as writefile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(readfile)
    writeCSV = csv.writer(writefile)
    for row in sorted(readCSV, key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
        bad_port = row[1][:4],row[4][2::]
        print(bad_port)
        writeCSV.writerow(bad_port)
```

If you want to include the number of times each key occurred, you can easily include that in the program, too. I would refactor slightly to separate the reading and the writing.

```py
import csv
import operator
from collections import Counter

with open('bad_voice_ports.csv') as readfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(readfile)
    rows = []
    counts = Counter()
    for row in readCSV:
        rows.append([row[1][:4], row[4][2::]])
        counts[row[1][:4]] += 1

with open('bad_voice_portsnew20200103SORTED.csv', 'w') as writefile:
    writeCSV = csv.writer(writefile)
    for row in sorted(rows):
        print(row)
        writeCSV.writerow([counts[row[0]]] + row)
```

I would recommend to remove the header line from the CSV file entirely; throwing away (or separating out and prepending back) the first line should be an easy change if you want to keep it.
(Also, hard-coding input and output file names is problematic; maybe have the program read them from `sys.argv[1:]` instead.)

Comment: I guess you are right, but with this code I still can't seem to split the data and pass the next value to the next column. Using writeCSV.writerow(*bad_port) in the end I get a TypeError: writerow() takes exactly one argument (2 given) error, while if I use  writeCSV.writerow(bad_port) I get Dsla,i followed by a new empty line and then aart, 2xxxxxxxx all in the same column. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Sorry about that. Try without the splat `*`

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code seems great and I will examine it more! I don't quite understand why it adds the data to the new file in the form Dsla, i followed my a blank line and then count, aart, 2xxxxxxx.

Answer (score 0):

So my suggestion is failry simple. As i stated in a previous comment there is good documentation on CSV read and write in python here: https://realpython.com/python-csv/

As per an example, to read from a csv the columns you need you can simply do this:

```
>>> file = open('some.csv', mode='r')
>>> csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
>>> for line in csv_reader:
...     print(line["Dslam_Name"] + " " + line["Ani"])
...
```

This would return:

```
aart-m1-m1 302xxxxxxxxx
```

Now you can just as easilly create a variable and store the column values there and later write them to a file or just open up a new file wile reading lines and writing the column values in there. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this but I really want to keep just the aart part of the Dslam_Name and the 2xxxxxxxxx part from the Ani, hence I'm using the row[1][:4],row[4][2::] split. The https://realpython.com/python-csv/ is really helpful though, thank you!

Comment: @dimitris1780 you can use print(line["Dslam_Name"][:4] + " " + line["Ani"][2::])

Comment: I create 2 variables in the form that I want and display them as I like using print but the problem is (I guess as mentioned above) that I am forcing them to a single column. When I write the variables to the new csv file they are still in the same column, not in two different columns.

Comment: the output should also be csv? if so then you can just  print both values separated with a comma into a file (one pair per line).

Comment: Yes, I would like to have the output to a new csv, into two separated columns as in that way I will be able to perform actions in each separated column, e.g. pivot/sort/search etc. Having the values seperated by comma or space will not allow me to do that.

Comment: first of all. CSV stands for CommaSeparatedValue. You dont have columns you have comma separated values :) So you should be good if you write var1,var2 into your new csv. Each time on a new line :)

Comment: You were right :) I saved the data to an xls file instead of csv and used '\t' to write var2 to the 2nd column :)

Comment: @dimitris1780 you an mark the answer correct then. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After the help from @tripleee and @marxmacher my final code is

```
import csv
import operator
from collections import Counter

with open('bad_voice_ports.csv') as csv_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    sortedlist = sorted(readCSV, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    line_count = 0
    rows = []
    counts = Counter()
    for row in sortedlist:
        Dslam = row[1][:4]
        Ani = row[4][2:]
        if line_count == 0:
            print(row[1], row[4])
            line_count += 1
        else:
            rows.append([row[1][:4], row[4][2::]])
            counts[row[1][:4]] += 1
            print(Dslam, Ani)
            line_count += 1
    for row in sorted(rows):
        f = open("bad_voice_portsnew202001061917.xls","a+")
        f.write(row[0] + '\t' + row[1] + '\t' + str(counts[row[0]]) + '\n')
        f.close()
    print('Total of Bad ports =', str(line_count-1))
```

As with this way the desired values/columns are extracted from the initial csv file and a new xls file is generated with the desired values stored in different columns and the total values per key are counted, along with the total of entries.

Thanks for all the help, please feel free for any improvement suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sorted`:

```
import csv
_h, *data = csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))
with open('new_csv.csv', 'w') as f:
  write = csv.writer(f)
  csv.writerows([_h, *sorted([(i[1], i[4]) for i in data], key=lambda x:x[0])])
```